# Mime type for text files

Tags: android

When I use the intent ACTION_GET_CONTENT on kitkat and I use the mime `*/*`, the UI picker shows me even local storage and other sources. When I use text/plain, it doesn't show the local storage but only dropbox (it's an app I've got installed). What is the mime type to use to show even the local storage? I could use `*/*` but I don't want to show sources like foto or audio sources because I need only text files.

Answer (score 3):

Starting in API level 19 you can use  EXTRA_MIME_TYPES

```
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_MIME_TYPES
```

Example from a forum:

```
  private static final String[] ACCEPT_MIME_TYPES = {
        "application/x-pkcs12",
        "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
        "application/x-x509-user-cert",
        "application/x-x509-server-cert",
        "application/x-pem-file",
        "application/pkix-cert"
  };


  final Intent openIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            openIntent.setType("*/*");
            openIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, ACCEPT_MIME_TYPES);
```

So if you're lucky enough to build for API 19 you just have to figure out which 
mime-types you need to list.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: it works only on **Samsung** phone with API 19+.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("application/vnd.foo.bar");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[]{"application/x-zip", "application/vnd.foo.bar",
                "application/octet-stream"});
        intent.setClassName("com.android.documentsui", "com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity");
```